# Xamarin Forms ShellContent Open Browser

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms Shell. On one of my `<ShellContent>` items in my `<TabBar>`, I just want to open a browser that navigates to a certain URL. I don't have a need to set the `ContentTemplate`.

It appears that with the `<MenuItem>` you can set a `Command` but I don't have the ability to use `MenuItem` in `<TabBar>`. Any ideas on how I could achieve this with `ShellContent`?

```
<ShellContent
    Title="Open Browser"
    Icon="browser.png"
    Style="{StaticResource DefaultShell}"
    ???=??? />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use MenuItem in Tabbar. [Menuitem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#menu-items) can be optionally added to the flyout instead of Tabbar.

> I just want to open a browser that navigates to a certain URL.

You still need to set the ContentTemplate with a Page :

```
<Tab Title="browser" Icon="browser.png">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:BrowserPage}"/>
</Tab>
```

Then in that page, navigates to a certain URL:

```
public BrowserPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Launcher.OpenAsync("https://www.xamarin.com");
}
```

Or use a WebView to load the url:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView HeightRequest="1000" WidthRequest="1000" Source="https://www.xamarin.com"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I uploaded my sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Shell-loadUrl) and you can check.

Comment: Makes sense. I was hoping there was a way to run a command from ShellContent that would allow me run something like `Launcher.OpenAsync("https://www.xamarin.com")` but that doesn't appear possible. Thanks.